# LWC Code not displaying data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am new to LWC. I am trying to print data fetched using Apex in LWC but it is neither printing data nor throwing error:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Call Apex" icon-name="utility:announcement">
        <div class="slds-var-m-around_small">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" onclick={buttonHandler} label="Show or Hide Data"></lightning-button>
                <template if:true={flag}>                           
                        <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
                            <div class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small" key={account.Id}>
                                <p><strong>Name : </strong>{account.Name}</p>
                                <p><strong>Industry : </strong>{account.Industry}</p>
                            </div>
                        </template>                         
                </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';
export default class Wireapex11 extends LightningElement {
        flag = false;
        accounts = [];
        buttonHandler()
        {
                flag = true;
                getAccounts().then(function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                        this.accounts = result;
                }).catch(function(error){
                        console.error(error);
                });
        }
}



public class AccountController
{
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccounts()
    {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Type, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used this :

```
getAccounts().then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    this.accounts = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
            console.error(error);
    });
}
```

You need to use arrow function instead. Only then `this.accounts` will refer to outer scope.
If you use `this` keyword inside `function` it tries to find the account reference within that `function`.

Also correct this: `this.flag = true;`

```
    getAccounts().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.accounts = result;
    }).catch(function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
```